# How to add more monitors in heartbeat.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying out **Uptime** feature in Kibana. I've downloaded Heartbeat and ran it with default setting. It works okay.

However, when I tried to add more monitors in `heartbeat.monitors` in `heartbeat.yml`. I run into an error.

The below is the default, and it runs okay.
`haertbeat.yml`

```
# Configure monitors inline
heartbeat.monitors:
- type: http

  # List or urls to query
  urls: ["http://localhost:9200"]

  # Configure task schedule
  schedule: '@every 10s'

  # Total test connection and data exchange timeout
  #timeout: 16s
```

However, when I add the following, I get an error.

```
# Configure monitors inline
heartbeat.monitors:
- type: http

  # List or urls to query
  urls: ["http://localhost:9200"]

  # Configure task schedule
  schedule: '@every 10s'

  # Total test connection and data exchange timeout
  #timeout: 16s  
- type: icmp                       <------ When I try to add tcp or icmp,
   schedule: '@every 10s'          <------ I get an error. I am doing something
   hosts: ["localhost"]            <------  wrong. How can I add more monitors?
```

```
PS C:\Program Files\Heartbeat> Start-Service heartbeat
Start-Service : Service 'heartbeat (heartbeat)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service heartbeat on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service heartbeat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

When I erase what I wanted to add, it works fine. How can I add more monitors in `heartbeat.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly believe that its an indentation issue in the YAML file.

Look at your icmp monitor:

```
- type: icmp                       <------ When I try to add tcp or icmp,
   schedule: '@every 10s'          <------ I get an error. I am doing something
   hosts: ["localhost"]            <------  wrong. How can I add more monitors?
```

There are whitespaces before the `schedule` and `hosts` settings.

Now look at the default monitor:

```
heartbeat.monitors:
- type: http

  # List or urls to query
  urls: ["http://localhost:9200"]

  # Configure task schedule
  schedule: '@every 10s'

  # Total test connection and data exchange timeout
  #timeout: 16s
```

Align the settings exactly under the `type` field and run it again.